# How to fetch all dates between from Date to Date in Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, nsdate

I am getting two time stamps which is From Date, To Date from server response.

But, I want to fetch all the dates between of them and need to display in tableview.

Any suggestions to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: You can extract day , month  and year using DateComponent. After that increment day or month or year till end date.

Comment: will it give how many days between there?

Comment: this may help you to find dates [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292887-datecomponents)

Comment: @Savitha, but, I want to print all the dates between of them

Comment: @Savitha, any idea about how to filter array of dates with particular date? and then I need to some other filter.

Comment: You can filter using array.filter API.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159381/discussion-between-anilkumar-ios-developer-and-savitha).

Comment: @Savitha, any idea about this issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399547/how-to-load-js-file-into-html-in-uiwebview-in-objective-c