# How to load .js file into HTML in UIWebview in Objective-C

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iphone, webview

I am doing some waves animation in my existing iOS app. Its implemented by Objective-C language. 
So, I have .Js and HTML pages. In HTML page, I am loading .js file and trying to loading HTML file with UIWebview.

But, Always its showing Blank white screen, I searched so many forums too, I found only loading HTML pages only able to found, I din't found for loading .js file into HTML page for UIWebview.

[image]

// Following is my code.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIWebView *animationView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *filePathh=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"voicewave" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@",filePathh);
    NSString *htmlstring=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePathh encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

 //   [_animationView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePathh]]];
    [_animationView loadHTMLString:htmlstring baseURL:nil];
}
```

And HTML code is

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .container {
        background: rgba(232, 17, 17, 0);
        }
    </style>
<body>
<div id="container-ios9" class="container"></div>
<script src="wave9.js"></script>
<script>
         var $wave_ios9 = document.getElementById('container-ios9');
         var SW9 = new Wave9({
                         height: 40,
                         speed: 0.2,
                         amplitude: 0.1,
                         container: $wave_ios9,
                         autostart: false,
         });
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone suggest me, how to fix this and load my animation code in Webview. Even I tried with WkWebview, but, same result came.

If its only Html file without .js, its loading, but, if I inclued .js file into html file, its showing blank white screen.

Comment: @Savitha any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML file seems fine

Load it into the Webview with `loadRequest` rather than with `loadHTMLString`

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSString *filePathh=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"voicewave" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];

        NSLog(@"%@",filePathh);
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: filePathh];
        NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [_animationView loadRequest:request];
    }
```

Make sure the .html and the .js files are in the same folder and add this folder to your project - choose create folder reference, not a group when prompted.

This should do it.

Comment: I followed your steps, but, still same blank screen is coming.

Comment: Did you test it in a browser? In your xcode project choose the html file -> show in finder. Open it in Safari and see if it works there as expected.

Comment: I found finally, its issue with HTML not loading properly .js file.

Comment: is your js running successfully? because for me, the html file is running but the js for some reason is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm loading a local html file and a js included in the html using the code below. It's working without any problems. Maybe the problem you're facing is caused by not setting the baseUrl when loading the html string, so webview does not know where to search for the js file.

```
NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"html_filename" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *htmlStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
WKWebView *wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[wkWebView loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[htmlPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]]];
```

Comment: same blank screen coming.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is js file code is not loading properly with HTML file. This is the issue. We have fixed it finally.